# There is a way to calculate and plot means and standard deviation of multi-column python dataframe?

Tags: python, seaborn, natural-logarithm, histplot

I have three pandas dataframes with more columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import seaborn as sns
data = np.random.randint(0, 1001, size=(1000, 100))
data[data < 0] = 0
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I want to plot all the dataframes' columns as unstacked histograms in logscale.

```
num_bin = 30
figure, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex=True, figsize=(15,5))
axes[0].set_title('log df1')
axes[1].set_title('log df2')
axes[2].set_title('log df3')
sns.histplot(ax=axes[0],data=df1[df1>0], bins=num_bin, log_scale=True, weights=None, legend=False, palette='viridis', alpha=0.1)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[1],data=df2[df2>0], bins=num_bin, log_scale=True, weights=None, legend=False, palette='husl', alpha=0.1)
sns.histplot(ax=axes[2],data=df3[df3>0], bins=num_bin, log_scale=True, weights=None, legend=False, palette='inferno', alpha=0.1)
plt.show()
```

I like to see the mean of each bin (calculated on all columns of the dataframes) plotted as a dot and the standard deviation plotted as a vertical line.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: I don't know how to compute the mean and standard deviation by using the number of bin. In other words, I don't know the bin edges

Comment: FYI, you don't need to create separate dataframes for what you are doing. You can just do `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` and use the same one 3 times for each plot.